# How to repeatedly run bash script every N seconds?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a shell script printing some statistics like disk info, memory use and so on. But it shows information only once after the script runs and exits. Can I make this script be run repeatedly (like `htop` for example) or something like that? I want this info to be updated every 5-10 seconds.

Comment: If it suffices to run once a minute, you could use coron to run your script. Otherwise youl have to do some loop and actually run you script like a service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430330/best-way-to-make-a-shell-script-daemon

Comment: Yeah, but it will close current tty everytime. I mean to work without closing...

Comment: What about wrapping your script (or its contents) in `while :; do script; sleep 10; done`?

Comment: very close subset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299704/run-command-every-second

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A slight improvement to my comment: if your script exits with *true* (e.g. when it ends with `exit 0`), you can run

```
while script; do sleep 10; done
```

This is the canonical way to repeat a command as long as it doesn't fail.

Comment: My variant looks like this:

`while true; do`
*code goes here...*
`sleep 10`
`done`

It works well!

Comment: @alexkowalski Perfect! The next step would be to *accept* the answer you like best by clicking the check mark below the arrows.

Comment: I have a python script that gives output called test.png. is it possible to change the name for every output (after 10 seconds) like test.png, tes1.png, tes2.png ....?

Comment: @user1883491 Yes; but that's an entirely diffent question. You'd have to introduce a variable such as `i=0` and increment it in the loop with `: $((++i))`.

Comment: This one liner is superior , while sleep 1; do echo "Hi"; done  - found at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever

Comment: How can we handle if the command fails?

Comment: @alper If it fails, code following the `done` is executed (as the `while` loop is left).

Answer (score 37):

In linux you can use the `watch` program to repeat an action. Assuming that `script.sh` is executable:

```
watch -n 10 path/to/script.sh
```

Would run it every 10 seconds.

To make your script executable, you can use `chmod +x script.sh`. Don't forget to add the shebang

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to the first line (assuming that it's a bash script).

If you're running the script from your current directory, you can then do:

```
watch -n 10 ./script.sh
```

Comment: Yeah, it also works but i have to use "sh" additional!
`watch -n 10 sh script.sh`

Comment: Or you could add a shebang `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your script and make it executable. Note that in general, if you mean `bash`, don't use `sh` instead as it may be a different shell.

Comment: I wrote as example, but if i use `watch -n 10` without `sh` or `bash` it doesn't work (

Comment: Is your script executable? Try `chmod +x script` (and don't forget to add the shebang as I stated above). If the script is in the current directory, you may also need to use `watch -n 10 ./script`

Comment: This doesnt work with bash commands like ll etc. This one liner from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever is superior - while sleep 1; do echo "Hi"; done

Comment: What is the error you receive when trying to use `watch` with `ll` on your system?

Comment: Just add quotes around the expression: `watch -n 10 "bash path/to/script.sh"`

Comment: @zabop I rolled back your edit because the rest of the answer already goes into detail about how to make an executable script with a shebang, so running it as `bash path/to/script.sh` is redundant.