# How to make bash script execute command at regular intervals

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script that will run for appoximately 30 minutes at a time. I've got it running stable as far as that part goes. I've been looking for a way to make it fire certain commands at inervals of every 3 minutes while running. I've not had any luck, so I turn to those of you that may know more about bash than I.

Any suggestions?

Here is what I have in mind of doing.

```
START=$(date +%s);

while read LINE <&3; do
END=$(date +%s);
if [[ $(($END-$START)) > 180 || $(($END-$START)) == 180  ]]
then
$START=$(date +%s);
run command
fi
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Add a cron job to make it run every 3 minutes.

```
*/3 * * * * /path/to/script
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the `watch` command?? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever)

(Second answer on here: [Run command every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299704/run-command-every-second))

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop in the background:

```
{ while /bin/true; do some_command; sleep 180; done; } &
loop_pid=$!
```

Then before the main script exits, kill the background loop:

```
kill $loop_pid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the same script from same script.

```
$ cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash

# commands
# commands

sleep 1800
sh $0
```